# getRecord returns undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';

import { getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';



const FIELDS = [
    'Sales__Toolkit__c.Primary_Quote__c',
    'Sales__Toolkit__c.Payment_Terms__c'
];

export default class igt_newQuoteBuildInput extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api formFactor;

    @track isPrimary;
    @track revenueModel;


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wireRecord({data, error}){
        console.log('  data --> ' + JSON.stringify(data) + ' error -->  ' + JSON.stringify(error) )
        if(data){
            this.isPrimary = data.fields.Primary_Quote__c.value;
            this.revenueModel = data.fields.Payment_Model__c.value;
        } else if(error){
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

data is undefined but so is error, yet there's always a value on the primary_quote field since it's a boolean and the Payment_Terms__c is a required field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if the `recordId` is being retrieved? Check these [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context).

I tested a similar component using `Contact` instead of `Payment_Terms__c`, adding it into the Contact Record page and works as designed:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = ['Contact.Name', 'Contact.Phone'];

export default class TestRecordId extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    contact;
    name;
    phone;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wireRecord({data, error}){
        console.log('  data --> ' + JSON.stringify(data) + ' error -->  ' + JSON.stringify(error) )
        if(data){
            this.contact = data;
            this.name = this.contact.fields.Name.value;
            this.phone = this.contact.fields.Phone.value;
        } else if(error){
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you don't need the `@track` anymore.
Note 2: I noticed that the browser shows the entries twice, one with both `error` & `data` being `undefined`.

[image]